# How to create a web API PUT handler (Python, Google App Engine)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is an assigned class project.

I have to create a web API that is hosted on the Google app engine. It has to store data and support GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE operations. Implicit in the requirements is that I can't throw a framework at it and call it a day. Flask etc. seem to make this really easy but are not an option.

My idea is to simulate a very simple record store API. The API allows getting album or artist information, editing that information or deleting that information.

To get started, I want a Python script to send a PUT request to the API and then have the API make a response. The course materials do not explain how to do even this basic operation. I cannot find any resource anywhere that explains it.

I gather I would use urllib2 in the test script and make a request with that. Something like:

`urbllib2.Request("app_name.appspot.com\albums\something, data=an_album_to_add, method='PUT')`

In the API, I would have a handler like this:

`def add_album(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self):
        #do a data store operation
        #return something via HTTP, something to indicate success or failure....`

This is as much as I can figure out. Am I on the right track? How do I send back a response to the client which sent a request to the API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track!

If you want to return JSON, simply add this to the end of your `put` method:

```
    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    out_json = json.dumps(out_dict, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")
    self.response.write(out_json)
```

Where `out_dict` is a Python dict of whatever you want to return.